# String of month and year as sections headers titles

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I created a project in Xcode with core data in it.

I have my NSManagedObjects model with a "startDate" property.
I also added some custom functions to my model to get the month and year string from "startDate":

```
func monthName() -> String {
        let date = self.startDate!
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([.Month], fromDate: date)
        var monthName: String = ""
        switch components.month {
        case 1:
            monthName = "January"
        case 2:
            monthName = "February"
        case 3:
            monthName = "March"
        case 4:
            monthName = "April"
        case 5:
            monthName = "May"
        case 6:
            monthName = "June"
        case 7:
            monthName = "July"
        case 8:
            monthName = "August"
        case 9:
            monthName = "September"
        case 10:
            monthName = "October"
        case 11:
            monthName = "November"
        case 12:
            monthName = "December"
        default:
            monthName = "WRONG"
        }
        return monthName
    }
    func yearString() -> String {
        let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
        let components = calendar.components([.Year], fromDate: self.startDate!)
        let stringFromYear = String(components.year)
        return stringFromYear
    }
```

What I now want to do is create custom header for sections.

I have my tableView that is managed by fetchedRestulsController (and sectionNameKeyPath is set to "monthName".

I created custom file called "HeaderTableViewCell" and it contains "monthNameLabel" and "yearLabel" outlets.

I set up my header like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionHeaderCell") as! HeaderTableViewCell
    let dateString = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections![section].name
    headerCell.monthNameLabel.text = dateString

    return headerCell
}
```

And it groups my dates based on the month.

I want to write a code that will group my dates based on their month and year but I do not have the idea how to do it.

Have I started implementing this correctly? Or maybe I'm doing it completely wrong?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual question but do not hard code the month names like you are. The `NSDateFormatter` class provides the `monthSymbols` function. Or format the date using an `NSDateFormatter` with the `MMMM` format string. Either of those two solutions is much better than your `switch` statement with hardcoded names.

Comment: Thanks! I will try it!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the results I wanted.

I combined the monthName and yearString function into one "dateName", so I get the String of for example: "January 2016".

Then I use "dateName" as sectionNameKeyPath in fetchedResultsController.

Then in viewForHeaderInSection I use my custom cell and set its monthNameLabel.text and yearLabel.text as is:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionHeaderCell") as! HeaderTableViewCell
        let dateString = self.fetchedResultsController?.sections![section].name
        let arrayOfString = dateString?.characters.split{$0 == " "}.map(String.init)
        headerCell.monthNameLabel.text = arrayOfString![0]
        headerCell.yearLabel.text = arrayOfString![1]

        return headerCell
    }
```

Works perfectly for now :)

Comment: And boom. It does not work now, but I did not change a thing in it. What a weird case.